# how to get public key of nami wallet

Tags: nami-wallet, public-key

wondering whats the simplest way to get the pkh for nami-wallet? Is it possible through the webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in getting the holdings of that pkh as a list after getting the pkh, but I think this is a user input type of deal.

I don't think you can get the pkh for a random wallet on nami without other information such as the wallet address (I mean how is it gonna know which address your requesting the pkh for?).

Also if your using smart contracts, I think whatever the solution is would work any address on the chain regardless of which wallet they are using.

Comment: maybe not the pkh or public key of any specific address, but an account-level public key should be an option

Comment: Hi @zhekson can you please clarify what you mean by account level pk and how this differs from the pk of an address?

Comment: Scroll down to the "HD Sequential wallets (à la BIP-44)" [here](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/concepts/address-derivation)

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of (so far) is:

1. Grab your bech32 address from the Nami wallet interface (e.g. `addr_***`)
2. Inspect that address with the [cardano-address](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses) tool with this command:

```
echo <YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE addr_...> | cardano-address address inspect
```

3. You should be able to find the hex hash in the output under the property `spending_key_hash`

ALTERNATIVELY, there's another easy way where you dont need to download `cardano-address`. By using the `cardano-address` demo here [Cardano Address Inspector](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-addresses/demo/).

- Unfortunately they have disabled the hex output option, not sure why
- But I realized that they do print the `cardano-address` output into the console... So if you open the browser inspect tool and hit Inspect again, you should be able to find the hex hash with the key `spending_key_hash`